# How many chickens would it take to overthrow a farmer?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, fauna

Hopefully this is the right place to ask this question.

I'm looking for intelligent, logical answers, and will accept from any viewpoints (e.g. farming, political). Take any factors into account and feel free to propose any methodologies and reasoning. However ultimately I am looking for a number if possible.

To clarify, I am thinking something along the lines of the movie "Chicken Run" with real-world limitations placed upon all chickens and other factors.

Comment: Are the chickens suddenly sentient or otherwise changed from normal chickens?

Comment: This does include intelligence; chickens in this scenario are your normal average chicken, with no unrealistic expectations

Comment: It seems that this forum is becoming a honeypot for joke questions. Will it endanger beta?

Comment: Without specifying the conditions the question is impossible to estimate. Are the chickens in individual cages they cannot individually escape from? Is the farmer alone? Does he have employees? There is a big difference between a farmer in charge of a battery of secure cages, and a farmer surrounded by a huge flock of chickens next to a deep, fast flowing river.

Comment: This not a serious question but a joke. Suggest to close.

Comment: Also, what would you call chickens overthrowing a farm? Is the farmer being pecked to death by his chicken enough or do you additionally want the chickens to run the farm in some sort of 'Weekend at Bernie's' situation?

Comment: Why do you find this question a joke? It seems like a rather reasonable and creative question to ask given the movie context.

Comment: I think the main issue is if the farmer is aware that the chicken are sentient. If he is aware he will pick on chicken one on one. If he is not aware, a single chicken might try to "electrify" a door knob with the power cord for a bulb.

Comment: This question is neither world building, nor, topic aside, well asked.  We should remove this.

Comment: Not to mention that this question dictates its own answer.  If chickens in this scenario are just chickens then they do not have the self awareness and capacity to attack the farmer for a reason as complex as this...which should be pretty obvious.  Hence my inability to take this seriously.

Comment: You should read George Orwell : animal farm

Comment: There are a LOT of chickens in the world. A lot. If they haven't figured out a way to take over yet, they won't.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would argue that no number of unaugmented, non-sentient chickens will be able to overthrow a farmer and continue running the farm.

Firstly, the [chicken's ancestors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_junglefowl) does not naturally behave as a pack animal, in fact, they will fight with each other when confined in close captivity, which [necessitates that their beaks be partially cut off](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debeaking). This makes it extremely difficult for them to cooperate, which is necessary for them to be able to physically overpower a human farmer.

Secondly, even in the unlikely case that the farmer is somehow debilated and dies from a heart attack (for example) after being attacked by a chicken, they will still have to contend with the remainder of human society. Chickens cannot run a farm, and unless the chickens are willing to slaughter their own kind / sell their unfertilised eggs in the delivery truck, the farm will quickly fail to deliver on its production contracts, and the rest of the chickens will be taken away when the farm is inevitably [foreclosed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreclosure).

Comment: Good answer; the bit about the ancestors naturally preferring fighting than cooperating is exactly the sort of info I was looking for! This is a serious question, so thanks for thinking it through!